# Small Gaps Between Edges When Using Solidify Modifier On Retopologized Mesh

Tags: retopology, solidify-modifier

I'm currently working on a model for a cat head in Blender and am trying retopology for the first time. I used the technique from [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2GNyEUvpD4&ab_channel=CGBoost)

This is my second attempt and I'm having the same problem I did with my first. When I try to apply the Solidify modifier to my mesh I get these really thin gaps between random edges:
[image]

I figured I had just poorly retopologized in my first attempt so I tried again, but alas still the same problem. Along with this, the modifier also adds unwanted faces to random sections like here on the ears:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I haven't finished this attempt as I wanted to test the modifier before going too far, any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :]

[Here is the file download.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t61PQkz7sj_AeyYBCteqqwZ8NV5DarZS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello, why are you using the Solidify modifier? Also maybe make sure that your vertices merge, select all and press M > Merge by Distance, increase a bit the Distance in the Operator Box if necessary

Comment: Maybe share your file so that we can check: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I am using a Solidify modifier to thicken the ears as they are too thin in places. I could avoid this by manually thickening them but since the issue seemed to have something to do with the edges themselves I thought it better to fix whatever's broken regardless. Also, sorry I completely forgot to include the file aha it was too large for blend-exchange but I've added a google drive download link to the original post! Keep in mind the retopology is currently unfinished.

Comment: there's a hole, for example here: https://www.zupimages.net/up/24/09/w5tu.jpg or some missing faces, for example here: https://www.zupimages.net/up/24/09/poyi.jpg if this is what you're talking about? You can easily fix that

Comment: @moonboots Ah yeah I saw those and have tried to fill them a few times but to no avail for some reason . However I don't know if that's what's causing this issue since the strange gaps and stray edges appear around areas without missing faces: https://shorturl.at/lzHI3 . I'll try to fill those gaps again and see if it fixes anything. One more thing, do you happen to know why that stray face on one of the ears also appears when using the modifier? https://shorturl.at/lMNX3 I can easily delete it, but I don't want to fiddle too much in case it damages other parts of the mesh.

Comment: the Solidify modifier will add thickness to the mesh so it may be one of these faces that intersect with an existing one? Hard to guess without the file, maybe highlight the problem with the annotation tool and share again?

Comment: @moonboots Maybe? Honestly I have no idea, here's the file again but with highlighted areas: https://shorturl.at/jlGKM

Comment: what you show seems to be the solidified face, not sure why you use this modifier, also try to work with quads, not ngons

Comment: @moonboots Ah alright I'll leave off the Solidify modifier then, I'm mostly just experimenting at the moment so whatever works works.
And ohhh I didn't know that about quads, okay will do! Thank you very much for your patience and help :]